# In Drupal How can I debug my custom module

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

In Drupal, I developed my own custom module to alter Query(Views). How can I debug it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With the [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel)

> A suite of modules containing fun for module developers and themers

See the module page for more details.

Comment: dpq(), in this case i think.

Comment: Yep, or sipmly `dpm((string) $query);`

Comment: Or dsm() or dvr()
Make sure you have anonymous permission to the module if you aren't logged in!

Comment: @BrandonTrecki `dsm()` is deprecated ;)